# an exception of redis::protocol_error from redis-cplusplus-client

Tags: c++, redis

I'm using a c++ client for redis which was checked out from https://github.com/jrk/redis-cplusplus-client .

The problem is that I always get an exception of `redis::protocol_error` , as often as I set up about 20 million key-value items into my Redis server.

The exception message is:

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'redis::protocol_error'
  what():  unexpected prefix for status reply
Aborted`

Does somebody know why and how can I fix it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deeping into my redis log, I finally figure out that there is something wrong with my redis RDB process since my system's `overcommit_memory` was set to `0`.

I have fixed this problem by running the command `sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1`.